# Food-service place in an amusement arcade

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What could the places that serve food within an amusement arcade (or similar establishment) be called? Is there some specific term(s) that are used here, or do usual terms for food places apply?

Example sentence: "We went to the _____ to get some lunch"

Comment: You seem to think we know the specific arcade you are thinking about, but you don't tell us anything about it. What sort of place is selling food? Fast food, coffee shop, bar with alcoholic drinks and bar snacks, sushi, noodles, with table service, full meals, snacks, hot food, cold food, prepared on or off site, cooked to order, vending machine? Is it a branded fast food concession, a coffee chain, or something run by the arcade? Is there seating at proper tables, a few stools, or  is it takeaway only? As it is, it could be anything from a counter or vending area to a restaurant or cafeteria.

Answer (score 2):

*Cafeteria*, as suggested by @LPH works well, and another term you could use may be 'food court.' Although a food court generally includes many different restaurants concentrated in one area, the word does have more of a commercial and fast-food feel to it.

Depending on your purposes, this may be suitable.

Per *[The Free Dictionary,](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/food+court)*

> An area, such as a section of a mall or of an airport, in which vendors sell food at stations about a common eating space.

And from *[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/food-court)*,

> a space, as in a shopping mall, with a concentration of fast-food stalls and usually a common eating area.

Answer (score 1):

The word "*cafeteria*" is proper.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cafeteria?q=cafeteria)) **cafeteria**  noun /ˌkæfəˈtɪəriə/ /ˌkæfəˈtɪriə/
> ​a restaurant where you choose and pay for your meal before you carry it to a table. Cafeterias are often found in factories, colleges, hospitals, etc.
> •  Consumer groups were urging school cafeterias to serve healthier food.

- We went to the cafeteria to get some lunch

Comment: In the US "cafeteria" is mostly used to refer to the food vendor in a school, office building, or maybe a department store.  "Food court" is more likely to be used in an amusement park setting.

Comment: @HotLicks A park is a vast place and I can conceive finding in it several  food preparation businesses gathered as a food court, but an amusement arcade is, I think, a much smaller place, and it would be surprising to find in it many small restaurants.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a stand offering food and drinks located within a larger venue, rather than a separate area with (say) its own seating.

In American English, this is a **concession stand.** [Collins defines it as:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/concession-stand)

> a stall where food, drinks, or other items are sold at a theatre or other venue

Concession stands in movie theaters tend to primarily sell things like popcorn and candy. At larger events or in larger spaces, though, they typically sell things like burgers or hot dogs that constitute a full meal.

Comment: Or just *concession*.

Comment: *Concession stand*, strictly speaking, implies that the business that operates the stand is **distinct** from the business that owns and operates the larger venue in which it is located (the amusement arcade in the OP's case): the word is used because, in such cases, one business grants a concession to the other to operate within a limited part of the venue controlled by it. It is true, though, that the general public often uses the term *concession* without having a full knowledge of the relevant business arrangements.

Comment: @jsw29 [Per Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concession_stand), the stands selling snacks to moviegoers were originally operated by independent vendors, typically outside of the theater itself. The word "concession stand" then continued to be used, even after the food came to be sold by within the theaters by its owners. Hence its present use for places that sell food within a venue regardless of ownership.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK it would probably be called a [snack bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snack_bar).